# HTML code appears while executing jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

HTML code appears when  I try to execute the jsp page. [This appears in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRdiQ.png)

I tried to change the contentType and language in the tag. But it did not work.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE> The Welcome JSP  </TITLE> </HEAD>
<BODY>

<H3> Welcome! </H3>
<P><B> Today is <%= new java.util.Date() %>.  Have a nice day! </B></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is my servlet code.

```
public class Add extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs)throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        int i=Integer.parseInt(rq.getParameter("t1"));
        int j=Integer.parseInt(rq.getParameter("t2"));
        int k=i+j;
        PrintWriter out=rs.getWriter();
        out.println("The sum is:"+k);
        RequestDispatcher rd=rq.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
        rd.include(rq,rs);
    }

}
```

I want the code to get rendered and view the output.

Comment: 1. you're writing invalid HTML ("The sum is: ...") to the response before the opening `<html>` tag. 2. You can't possibly include the JSP you posted: what appears on the screen has nothing to do with the HTML code you posted: not the same title, not the same markup, not the same content. 3. Why are you *including* rather than *forwarding*?

Comment: I edited the image. I had posted a wrong image

Comment: So it works fine. The problem is (I repeat), that you're sending non-HTML code to the response before including the JSP. Don't. Remove the 5 first lines of your method (at the very least, the 5th one, but then the 4th first ones become useless).

Comment: I want to display even the sum. How can I do that?

Comment: You store the sum in a request attribute, then you forward to the JSP, and the JSP gets the sum back from the request attribute.

Comment: request.setAttribute("sum",k);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request,response);
I did this but it didn't work

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: The sum is not displayed only the code inside html tags are displayed.

Comment: And what did you add in the JSP to display the sum? It won't appear by magic. As I said: *and the JSP gets the sum back from the request attribute*: did you do that?

Comment: <% request.getAttribute("sum"); %> I added this to jsp

Comment: That gets the attribute, but it doesn't *print* it. To fix that code, you would need `<%=`, not `<%`. But using scriptlets is really bad practice. Learn and use the JSP EL. All you need is `${sum}`

Comment: I added this to servlet request.getSession().setAttribute("sum", k); response.sendRedirect("/Welcome.jsp?sum=" + k); and this to jsp: <%= request.getAttribute("sum") %> I am getting null as result

Comment: Well, of course, since now instead of forwarding the request, containing the attribute, to the the JSP, you're telling the browser to send another, separate request, to the JSP, with a **parameter** named sum. A *parameter* is not the same thing as an *attribute*. And there's no reason to do a redirect at all in this case.